# Finding neighbouring elements of varying size from a 2D-array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, neighbours

So I'm trying to create a program, which finds all the neighbouring elements with given size of the neighbourhood in a 2-Dimensional array.
I already figured out how to find the 8 neighbouring elements from the perspective of the middle element, but say i want to find the 24 neighbouring elements and i'm looking for a solution for that.

I already tried to set the number 1 as a variable which can be changed, but it still doesn't find all of the neighbours of 24 elements if i set it to 2.

My solution for the 8 elements, if there is a way to expand upon it:

```
array[i-1][j-1]
array[i-1][j]
array[i-1][j+1]

array[i][j-1]
array[i][j+1]

array[i+1][j-1]
array[i+1][j]
array[i+1][j+1]
```

Comment: *"the 34 neighbouring elements"* which 34?

Comment: Yes 24(edited). But looking for a solution to check for varying sizes. 48 would be the next largest rectangle of neighbours.

Comment: Basically you want to have two loops from the -range to the +range while considering any borders and the middle.

Comment: Which 24 neighbours?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've tried with setting the from the -range to +range and borders. But it still doesn't seem to return right results for some reason.

```
int neighbourhoodSize = neighbourhoodSize/2; //Say size is t.ex. 11, has to be odd for rectangle
for (int k = 0; k < neighbourhoodSize; k++) {
    for (int i = k; i < arr.length - k; i++) {
        for (int j = k; j < arr[i].length - k; j++) {
            arr[i - k][j - k]
            arr[i - k][j]
            arr[i - k][j + k]
            arr[i][j - k]
            arr[i][j + k]
            arr[i + k][j - k]
            arr[i + k][j]
            arr[i + k][j + k]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you need the outerloop (at least if you want to write a function that finds all neighbours in a fixed distance). In the inner loop you should only check one arr-element. Also make sure its not the middle. -- I would have written a function with the signature findNeighbours(arr,x,y,range), where x and y indicate the position of the center piece in the array.

Comment: Also note that you should have edited this try into your question instead of posting it as an answer.